# How to copy sheet from excel in server to client

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy txt  sheet from excel A in server to excel B in client  and I need to create  .exe file. This code I had run on macro excel  xlsx. it worked. But when I use XLtoEXE.exe from http://orlando.mvps.org/XLtoEXEMore.asp to convert file to exe. Then I run it again in exe. It didn’t work . please tell me why? And how can I solve this problem?

```
Dim a As Workbook
Dim b As Workbook
Dim txt As String


Sub Button1_Click()
txt = InputBox("sheet name")
MsgBox txt
Set a = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\DESKTOP-E8QK413\Videos\target.xlsx.xlsx")
Set b = Workbooks("book1.xlsx")
a.Sheets(txt).Copy after:=b.Sheets(1)
a.Close

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: what line are you getting your error ? is `Workbooks("book1.xlsx")` already open ? if not you need to open it first. if it's open then the declaration should be `Set b = Workbooks("book1")`

Comment: any updates ? Is your problem solved ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. the error line is  `a.Sheets(txt).Copy after:=b.Sheets(1) `. this code run on book1.exe

Comment: you mean `book1.xlsm` ? right ?

Comment: I mean I convert book1.xlsm  to   book1.exe .  In  book1.xlsm this code is work but book1.exe is not work. I think about method `COPY` and use this 
`a.sheets(txt).UsedRange.copy
a.sheets(txt).Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
b.Sheets(1).Paste`

It's work !!!!

Thank to your help.

Comment: find my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you need an Exe file.
The code below is in a module in an Excel file with extension **.xlsm**, let's say *CopySheets.xlsm*.

Add a **CommandButton** to a user_form (or maybe in one of the sheets if it's easier), and have the code below in a module in this file.

```
Option Explicit

Dim a As Workbook
Dim b As Workbook
Dim txt As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

Sub Button1_Click()


Set a = Workbooks.Open("\\DESKTOP-E8QK413\Videos\target.xlsx.xlsx")

' (Filename in brackets must have full path and .xlsx extension)'
Set b = Workbooks.Open(AddWorkbookPath"Book1.xlsx")

txt = InputBox("Select Sheet name to Copy")
' loop through workbook a sheets and check is txt is found
For Each sht In a.Sheets
    ' sheet exists in workbook a
    If txt = sht.Name Then
        MsgBox "Sheet " & txt & " found in workbook " & a.Name
        GoTo Proceed_Copy
    End If
Next sht

' error message - sheet not found in worbook a
MsgBox "Sheet " & txt & " NOT found in workbook " & a.Name

' close both workbooks in case sheet name was not found
a.Close
b.Close

End

Proceed_Copy:
a.Sheets(txt).Copy after:=b.Sheets(1)
a.Close
b.Close (xlSaveChanges)

End Sub
```